# Polynomialception

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, polynomials, integer

Given two polynomials `f,g` of arbitrary degree over the integers, your program/function should evaluate the first polynomial in the second polynomial. `f(g(x))` (a.k.a. the *composition* `(fog)(x)` of the two polynomials)

#### Details

Builtins are allowed. You can assume any reasonable formatting as input/output, but the input and output format should match. E.g. formatting as a string

```
x^2+3x+5
```

or as as list of coefficients:

```
[1,3,5] or alternatively [5,3,1]
```

Furthermore the input polynomials can be assumed to be fully expanded, and the outputs are also expected to be fully expanded.

#### Examples

```
A(x) = x^2 + 3x + 5, B(y) = y+1
A(B(y)) = (y+1)^2 + 3(y+1) + 5 = y^2 + 5y + 9

A(x) = x^6 + x^2 + 1, B(y) = y^2 - y
A(B(y))= y^12 - 6y^11 + 15y^10 - 20y^9 + 15y^8 - 6y^7 + y^6 + y^4 - 2 y^3 + y^2 + 1

A(x) = 24x^3 - 144x^2 + 288x - 192, B(y) = y + 2
A(B(y)) = 24y^3

A(x) = 3x^4 - 36x^3 + 138x^2 - 180x + 27, B(y) = 2y + 3
A(B(y)) = 48y^4 - 96y^2
```

Comment: what about builtins?

Comment: @Maltysen *"Details: Builtins are allowed.(...)"*  :D

Comment: I think "any reasonable format" might be a bit stretchable. If a function that evaluates the polynomial is allowed, then the composition function `(.)` is an answer in Haskell. You probably mean some representation of the list of coefficients.

Comment: @xnor I don't think you could describe such a function as fully expanded.

Comment: Must we avoid needless zero coefficients?

Comment: @xnor If the Haskell function composition operatur would again fully expand the other functions that would be ok, but I doubt it does that. But thanks for mentioning the (leading) zero coefficients. I think these should be avoided. Or can you give me an example where these make sense?

Comment: The title! I just got it :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo Quick thinker =P

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, <s>86</s> 72 bytes

```hs
u!c=foldr1((.u).zipWith(+).(++[0,0..])).map c
o g=(0:)!((<$>g).(*))!pure
```

Defines a function `o` such that `o g f` computes the composition f ∘ g.  Polynomials are represented by a nonempty list of coefficients starting at the constant term.

### Demo

```
*Main> o [1,1] [5,3,1]
[9,5,1]
*Main> o [0,-1,1] [1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,1,-2,1,0,1,-6,15,-20,15,-6,1]
*Main> o [2,1] [-192,288,-144,24]
[0,0,0,24]
*Main> o [3,2] [27,-180,138,-36,3]
[0,0,-96,0,48]
```

### How it works

No polynomial-related builtins or libraries.  Observe the similar recurrences

f(x) = a + f₁(x)x ⇒ f(x)g(x) = a g(x) + f₁(x)g(x)x,
f(x) = a + f₁(x)x ⇒ f(g(x)) = a + f₁(g(x))g(x),

for polynomial multiplication and composition, respectively.  They both take the form

f(x) = a + f₁(x)x ⇒ W(f)(x) = C(a)(x) + U(W(f₁))(x).

The operator `!` solves a recurrence of this form for W given U and C, using `zipWith(+).(++[0,0..])` for polynomial addition (assuming the second argument is longer—for our purposes, it always will be).  Then,

`(0:)` multiplies a polynomial argument by x (by prepending a zero coefficient);
`(<$>g).(*)` multiplies a scalar argument by the polynomial `g`;
`(0:)!((<$>g).(*))` multiplies a polynomial argument by the polynomial `g`;
`pure` lifts a scalar argument to a constant polynomial (singleton list);
`(0:)!((<$>g).(*))!pure` composes a polynomial argument with the polynomial `g`.

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
Expand[#/.x->#2]&
```

Example usage:

```
In[17]:= Expand[#/.x->#2]& [27 - 180x + 138x^2 - 36x^3 + 3x^4, 3 + 2x]

              2       4
Out[17]= -96 x  + 48 x
```

Answer (score 7):

## TI-Basic 68k, 12 bytes

```
a|x=b→f(a,b)
```

The usage is straightforward, e.g. for the first example:

```
f(x^2+3x+5,y+1)
```

Which returns

```
y^2+5y+9
```

Comment: It seems like cheating to me to require the inputs to be in different variables. Does that matter for this answer?

Comment: Feel free to do so, I explicitly allowed any reasonable convenient input format.

Comment: Concerning the edit of your comment: yes it does matter.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the rules on this site. Is it correct for `→` to be 1 byte in TI-BASIC?

Comment: @asmeurer Indeed: TI-Basic is scored by the encoding used on the corresponding calculators. If you are interested in the details, you can read that [here on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4764/24877). A table of tokens can be found [here on ti-basic-dev](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 138 <s>156 162</s> bytes

The inputs are expected to be integer lists with smallest powers first.

```py
def c(a,b):
 g=lambda p,q:q>[]and q[0]+p*g(p,q[1:]);B=99**len(`a+b`);s=g(g(B,b),a);o=[]
 while s:o+=(s+B/2)%B-B/2,;s=(s-o[-1])/B
 return o
```

Ungolfed:

```py
def c(a,b):
 B=sum(map(abs,a+b))**len(a+b)**2
 w=sum(B**i*x for i,x in enumerate(b))
 s=sum(w**i*x for i,x in enumerate(a))
 o=[]
 while s:o+=min(s%B,s%B-B,key=abs),; s=(s-o[-1])/B
 return o
```

In this computation, the polynomial coefficients are seen as digits (which may be negative) of a number in a very large base. After polynomials are in this format, multiplication or addition is a single integer operation. As long as the base is sufficiently large, there won't be any carries that spill over into neighboring digits.

-18 from improving bound on `B` as suggested by @xnor.

Comment: Nice method. For `B`, would ``10**len(`a+b`)`` be enough?

Comment: @xnor Maybe... it's hard for me to tell.

Comment: +1 This is a really creative solution, and a nice use of bigints!!!

Comment: @xnor Now I've managed to convince myself that hte coefficient length is linear in the input length :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python + SymPy, <s>59</s> 35 bytes

```
from sympy import*
var('x')
compose
```

*Thanks to @asmeurer for golfing off 24 bytes!*

#### Test run

```
>>> from sympy import*
>>> var('x')
x
>>> f = compose
>>> f(x**2 + 3*x + 5, x + 1)
x**2 + 5*x + 9
```

Comment: SymPy has a `compose()` function.

Comment: @asmeurer It even simplifies the result... Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `var('x')` and require that the polynomial be expressed in `pi` :)

Comment: Where's the answer? It no longer defines any functions or does anything...

Comment: @feersum According to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7206), `compose` is a valid answer because it evaluates to a function.

Comment: @Dennis For the expression that evalutaes to a function case, I only meant if the entire code is the expression, not some substring of it.

Comment: @feersum I fail to see how this is different from an import plus a lambda.

Comment: @Dennis It isn't. The lambda should also be named, if you have a separate import statement.

Comment: @feersum That has never been the case. You just edited that meta post.

Comment: @Mego I indeed edited, as I just discovered that it was subject to misinterpretation.

Comment: @feersum You edited an accepted meta post to modify the policy for your own agenda. That's not ok.

Comment: @Mego I always intended this meaning, but my wording was ambiguous.

Comment: @feersum Though you may have thought your wording was ambiguous, it clearly was not for the rest of the community. We accepted the consensus that `from module import*;function` was a valid submission. Regardless, [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/45941) is a more recent policy, which allows imports and helper functions with unnamed lambdas.

Comment: @Mego The meta post is merely an opinion which others are free to agree or disagree with. Regarding Martin's answer, the point (1) saying "the submitted code" may evaluate to a function does not suggest to me that it's OK if only the last line evaluates to a function, rather than the entire code.

Comment: @feersum Defining helper functions also prevents the entire code from evaluating to a single function. Try it with `eval` and see for yourself.

Comment: @Mego Sure, what's your point? (BTW, that's not true in all cases in Python. I've written unnamed lambdas before where a helper function is defined in an optional argument).

Answer (score 3):

### Sage, 24 bytes

```py
lambda A,B:A(B).expand()
```

As of Sage 6.9 (the version that runs on http://sagecell.sagemath.org), function calls without explicit argument assignment (`f(2) rather than f(x=2)`) causes an annoying and unhelpful message to be printed to STDERR. Because STDERR can be ignored by default in code golf, this is still valid.

This is very similar to [Dennis's SymPy answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78335/45941) because Sage is a) built on Python, and b) uses [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), a computer algebra system very similar to SymPy in many ways. However, Sage is much more powerful than Python with SymPy, and thus is a different enough language that it merits its own answer.

[Verify all test cases online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjk0KgzAQhfeCdxjoIolNbU2stQUXehDBYgTBn5Bom96-o9m4mXm8-ebN9KOezQL2Z8MAS2yXVhkDBcxaTZRcW_W5TuswEE6-hMEJ7Kq1UdaCJ8OgK4ZmfLcNlLx6lbRisXK6mVrKwiAMtOmnBTrqagFnkJHDeuewtYQdxxk6Hkr4Li7gDoBII1dLNJN0Uxsn8hzj0HkKHygOPF6qUxzKbN_DVJlHPjbJb_sb4sFB7EqyP3mzRek=&lang=sage)

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 19 bytes

```
(a,b)->subst(a,x,b)
```

which lets you do

```
%(x^2+1,x^2+x-1)
```

to get

> %2 = x^4 + 2*x^3 - x^2 - 2*x + 2

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB with Symbolic Toolbox, 28 bytes

```
@(f,g)collect(subs(f,'x',g))
```

This is an anonymous function. To call it assign it to a variable or use `ans`.  Inputs are strings with the format (spaces are optional)

```
x^2 + 3*x + 5
```

Example run:

```
>> @(f,g)collect(subs(f,'x',g))
ans = 
    @(f,g)collect(subs(f,'x',g))
>> ans('3*x^4 - 36*x^3 + 138*x^2 - 180*x + 27','2*x + 3')
ans =
48*x^4 - 96*x^2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>51</s> 34 bytes

```
AQsM.t*LVG.usM.t.e+*]0k*LbHN0tG]1Z
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQsM.t%2aLVG.usM.t.e%2B%2a%5D0k%2aLbHN0tG%5D1Z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B5%2C3%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%2C-1%2C1%5D%0A%5B-192%2C288%2C-144%2C24%5D%2C%5B2%2C1%5D%0A%5B27%2C-180%2C138%2C-36%2C3%5D%2C%5B3%2C2%5D&debug=0).

Comment: when python outgolfs pyth

Comment: @downrep_nation not anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>239</strike> <strike>232</strike> 223 bytes

```py
r=range
e=reduce
a=lambda*l:map(lambda x,y:(x or 0)+(y or 0),*l)
m=lambda p,q:[sum((p+k*[0])[i]*(q+k*[0])[k-i]for i in r(k+1))for k in r(len(p+q)-1)]
o=lambda f,g:e(a,[e(m,[[c]]+[g]*k)for k,c in enumerate(f)])
```

A 'proper' implementation that does not abuse bases. Least significant coefficient first.

`a` is polynomial addition, `m` is polynomial multiplication, and `o` is composition.

Comment: Is `m([c],e(m,[[1]]+[g]*k))` not the same as `e(m,[[c]]+[g]*k)`?

Comment: @Neil Good call, can squash two in one with that!

Comment: `a=lambda*l:map(lambda x,y:(x or 0)+(y or 0),*l)`

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Right, I added it, thanks :)

Comment: It might be possible to simplify your polynomial addition, since I think one list will always be longer than the other, so you don't need the `( or 0)` in that version.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>150</s> 103 bytes

```
(f,g)=>f.map(n=>r=p.map((m,i)=>(g.map((n,j)=>p[j+=i]=m*n+(p[j]||0)),m*n+(r[i]||0)),p=[]),r=[],p=[1])&&r
```

Accepts and returns polynomials as an array a = [a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ...] that represents a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>*x + a<sub>2</sub>*x<sup>2</sup> ...

Edit: Saved 47 bytes by switching from recursive to iterative polynomial multiplication, which then allowed me to merge two `map` calls.

Explanation: *r* is the result, which starts at zero, represented by an empty array, and *p* is *g*<sup>*h*</sup>, which starts at one. *p* is multiplied by each *f*<sub>*h*</sub> in turn, and the result accumulated in *r*. *p* is also multiplied by *g* at the same time.

```
(f,g)=>f.map(n=>            Loop through each term of f (n = f[h])
 r=p.map((m,i)=>(           Loop through each term of p (m = p[i])
  g.map((n,j)=>             Loop though each term of g (n = g[j])
   p[j+=i]=m*n+(p[j]||0)),  Accumulate p*g in p
  m*n+(r[i]||0)),           Meanwhile add p[i]*f[h] to r[i]
  p=[]),                    Reset p to 0 each loop to calculate p*g
 r=[],                      Initialise r to 0
 p=[1]                      Initialise p to 1
)&&r                        Return the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby 2.4](https://www.ruby-lang.org) + [polynomial](http://adrianomitre.github.io/Polynomial/website/index.html), 41+12 = 53 bytes

Uses flag `-rpolynomial`. Input is two `Polynomial` objects.

If someone outgolfs me in vanilla Ruby (no polynomial external library), I will be very impressed.

```
->a,b{i=-1;a.coefs.map{|c|c*b**i+=1}.sum}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 34 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzLCsIwEEV/ZZYzcQSbiBb7KT7KhLoIJGmwFcavj5GuXd3D4XCTaEhSn1okT2OZ4yfPKUgcoyQ/CVxudSO8Cvs7byEub7@s6FlZiKgO5RXyin9f0J5hD11/MAo76Fxv9GGbcacGrinX9sjwQ2uUaKhf)

```
lambda([a,b],expand(subst(b,x,a)))
```