# Rudin-Shapiro sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, binary

The [Rudin-Shapiro sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudin%E2%80%93Shapiro_sequence) is a sequence of \$1\$s and \$-1\$s defined as follows: \$r_n = (-1)^{u_n}\$, where \$u_n\$ is the number of occurrences of (possibly overlapping) \$11\$ in the binary representation of \$n\$.

For example, \$r_{461} = -1\$, because \$461\$ in binary is \$111001101\$, which contains \$3\$ occurrences of \$11\$: \$\color{red}{\underline{11}}1001101\$, \$1\color{red}{\underline{11}}001101\$, \$11100\color{red}{\underline{11}}01\$.

This is sequence [A020985](https://oeis.org/A020985) in the OEIS.

The first few terms of the sequence are:

```
1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1
```

### Task

Generate the Rudin-Shapiro sequence.

As with standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, you may choose to:

- Take an integer \$n\$ as input and output the \$n\$th term of the sequence.
- Take an integer \$n\$ as input and output the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.
- Take no input and output the sequence indefinitely.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

### Test cases

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> -1
4 -> 1
5 -> 1
6 -> -1
7 -> 1
8 -> 1
9 -> 1
10 -> 1
11 -> -1
12 -> -1
13 -> -1
14 -> 1
15 -> -1
16 -> 1
17 -> 1
18 -> 1
19 -> -1
```

Comment: Is there a maximum n that the program is required to handle?

Comment: @Tbw No. It depends on your language's integer type. If your language uses a floating-point type (e.g. JavaScript), floating-point inaccuracies are allowed.

Comment: It may be too late to ask, but could we output 2 distinct and consistent values instead of \$-1\$ and \$1\$?

Comment: @Arnauld No. The Rudin-Shapiro sequence is by definition a sequence of 1s and −1s.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(bin(n&n*2),13)%2*2-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjOvRCMpM08jTy1Py0hTx9BYU9VIy0jX8H9afpFCnkJmnkJRYl56qoaRoaYVF2dBEUh9nk6aRp6m5n8A)

Based on [Command Master's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266997/20260), but using the base-13 trick. We can tie with `1|~int(bin(n&n*2),13)%-2`, or `1|(n&n*2).bit_count()%-2` in Python 3.10.

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or n%4/3*-2^f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Ywv0ghT9VE31hL1yguTSNP30jzfxpITCEzT6EoMS89VcPIUNOKi7OgKDOvRCFPB6hG8z8A)

Outputs `True` for `1` for `n=0`. 34 bytes in Python 3 due to `//` twice. Weirdly, it seems shorter to switch between `1` and `-1` and back by (conditionally) xor-ing `-2` rather than multiplying by `-1`. It feels like there should be a way to use space after the `or`.

Comment: Why 13[?](http://www.example.com)

Comment: @l4m2 I think any odd base will do in principle, 13 is just the first one that can also digest the `b` from `0b...` in the binary literal.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 36 bytes

```python
lambda n:(-1)**bin(n&n*2).count('1')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3VXISc5NSEhXyrDR0DTW1tJIy8zTy1PK0jDT1kvNL80o01A3VNaFqNdPyixTyFDLzFIoS89JTNYwMNK24FAqKMoHK8nQU1HXt1HUU0jTyNKEaFiyA0AA)

## [Python 3.10+](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes, thanks to @xnor

```python
lambda n:(-1)**(n&n*2).bit_count()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3lXISc5NSEhXyrDR0DTW1tDTy1PK0jDT1kjJL4pPzS_NKNDShKjXT8osU8hQy8xSKEvPSUzWMDDStuBQKijKBavJ0FNR17dR1FNI08jShGhYsgNAA)

Comment: You can do `(n&n*2).bit_count()` starting with Python 3.10

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
BẠƝS-*
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer and yields the Rudin-Shapiro value.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//QuG6oMadUy0q/@G4tsOH4oKs//82NA)**

#### How?

```
BẠƝS-* - Link: non-negative integer, N
B      - convert N to binary
  Ɲ    - for neighbouring pairs:
 Ạ     -   all? -> 1 if [1,1] else 0
   S   - sum these
    -  - literal -1
     * - exponentiate
```

Answer (score 8):

## x86-64 machine code, 13 bytes

```
B0 01 D1 E1 73 04 79 02 F6 D8 75 F6 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFNT8MwDIbP8a8wRWPJ2NA@NA7byoUzF05IDE1ZmrRBWTq1KXRM@@sUhwkkuMTxa/t9nFaNcqW67tJ65ZpM46oOmS1vijv4Izm7/a9V1udRg81GBsq2TdCbDedG1kFJ54RAVcgKDbc@oBRLkPUOOT4mHG5yV26lQwNmwXblG0o3xAlUC1YXDrVqY8ZevUIdQx2D1zm1gV6Q8IEVsEoHEAmSMUTCTlp/RlW5Gp7ZgwElbwKOwGKFbA9LYKaskLeY4niJLa5wOr@ly/W1AEaNbE8vC4YnvZlNhrR@KwjBmDXIaeoKJ3OBafod9k2IHN5f@35sOsHv9No/SFVYr1GVmV4ksXxmAstKPP70YW88fSLOIeW88bXNvc6@lx8II55pqxexPOF7YZ1GfsALcmjvZ9Ht14H3LG4PQddi7cmpjUX6OE3lI@0EXfepjJN53Y12sykd9CNSmtXuCw)

Following the `fastcall` calling convention, this takes a 32-bit integer `n` in ECX and returns an 8-bit integer in AL.

In assembly:

```
f:  mov al, 1       # Set AL to 1.
r:  shl ecx, 1      # Left shift ECX by 1.
    jnc e           # Jump if CF is 0. CF is the bit shifted off the top.
    jns e           # Jump if SF is 0. SF is the top bit after the shift.
    neg al          # (If neither was true: both bits were 1) Negate AL.
e:  jnz r           # Jump back, to repeat, if the last calculated value
                    #  (which may be ECX or AL) is nonzero.
    ret             # Return.
```

---

### Another solution, 15 bytes

```
8D 04 09 21 C1 F3 0F B8 C1 D1 E8 D6 0C 01 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFNT8MwDD3Hv8IUDZJ9aWyCA6Nc4MqFE9KGpixN2khZOrUpdEL76xSnE5PgksTP9nvPjprkSnXdpfXKNZnGhzpktpwWj/AHcnb7H6uszyMGm40MFG2boDcbzo2sg5LOCYGqkBUabn1AKZYg6x1yfE04THNXbqVDA@aeOS1Ry3aMK61aHCGd78Ckz@JrHFPA9uVeEUtfRiiwuqhO0Q2w6fYQNM7a5ztgZYXS9WilA4gESReigZ20/uSkytX4ZG04pOBDwBewmCG2wxKYIQ7eYoqzJbb4gPPbO3qMRgIYFbI9DR4MTwYLm4xpulaQBGPWIKeuK7y5FZim/bVvQtTh12t/HYuOcO5e@xepCus1qjLT90lMnzSBZSV@/dbhYDZ/I51Dynnja5t7nfXmh8KIFbl6F8sjfhbWaeQHvCCG9mkR2c4MfGAxbqgWa09MbUzScprKR7UjdN23Mk7mdTfZLeZ00D@l1KvdDw)

In assembly:

```
f:  lea eax, [ecx + ecx]    # Set EAX to 2n.
    and ecx, eax    # Bitwise AND of n and 2n; this has a 1 for each 11 in n.
    popcnt eax, ecx # Set EAX to the number of 1 bits in that value.
    shr eax, 1      # Right shift by 1. The low bit goes into CF.
    .byte 0xD6      # Undocumented SALC instruction -- set AL to -CF.
    or al, 1        # Bitwise OR with 1: 0 becomes 1, -1 remains -1.
    ret             # Return.
```

Comment: If we want a version that only handles 8-bit inputs, then in your second version, we have the result in the parity flag after `and ecx, eax`.  However it takes some work to materialize it as +/- 1.  I can get down to 12 bytes with `setpe al / shl eax, 1 / dec eax` (in 32-bit mode so we have 1-byte `dec`).

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
b11¢®sm
```

Takes \$n\$ as input, and outputs the \$n^{th}\$ term.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ydDw0KJD64pz//83MTMEAA) or [verify the infinite sequence](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oY57Nua3/kwwNDy06tK449/9/AA).

Here an equal-bytes alternative:

```
bü*OÈ·<
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6fAeLf/DHYe22/z/b2JmCAA) or [verify the infinite sequence](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oY57Nua3/kw7v0fI/3HFou83//wA).

**Explanation:**

```python
b        # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary-string
 11¢     # Pop and count the amount of "11" substrings
    ®    # Push -1
     s   # Swap
      m  # Pop both, and push -1 to the power `binary(input).count("11")`
         # (after which the resulting 1 or -1 is output implicitly)
```

```python
b        # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary-string
 ü       # Pop it, and for each overlapping pair of bits:
  *      #  Multiply them together
         #  (1 if [1,1]; 0 if [0,0],[0,1],[1,0])
   O     # Take the sum of this list
    È    # Check if this sum is even (1 if even; 0 if odd)
     ·   # Double it (2 if even; 0 if odd)
      <  # Decrease it by 1 (1 if even; -1 if odd)
         # (after which the resulting 1 or -1 is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
ⁿ:¯1/+⬚0⌕1_1⋯
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4oG_OsKvMS8r4qyaMOKMlTFfMeKLrwoK4oi1ZiDih6EyMAo=)

```
ⁿ:¯1/+⬚0⌕1_1⋯
            ⋯  # bits
        ⌕1_1   # search for [1 1]
      ⬚0       # filling tiny arrays with excess zeros
    /+         # sum (count occurrences)
ⁿ:¯1           # raise negative one to this
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
_1^1#.2*/\#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/4w3jDJX1jLT0Y5St/mtypSZn5CukKZiYGcKYBv8B)

Answer (score 6):

## Java, <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```java
n->1|-n.bitCount(n&n*2)%2
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Neil*.

Takes \$n\$ as input, and outputs the \$n^{th}\$ term.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY89D4JADIZ3f0VDormTQISog4iLk4MujOpwnmiKUAgUE6P8djzQOLn04@3TvG2i7spJzrdWp6qqYKuQngMAJI7Li9Ix7Lq2F0CLjZGvcQkkA6M2AxMqVowadkAQtuSsvJdD7gl5ndfEgkY09uXQb4OOLepTatjvyj3HM2TGUERcIl33RyU/Zpe8FJ0hhpMAcBn6M5NsW/ZDgOhRcZy5ec1uYRY5JYG2tTiwZZOrBcr@ur@cNZ17P9DU8vtI074B)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                     // Method with Integer parameter and integer return-type
   1|                   //  Return 1 bitwise-OR'ed with:
     -                  //   The negative value of:
      n.bitCount(       //    The amount of bits in:
                 n      //     n
                  &n*2) //     Bitwise-AND'ed with doubled n
     %2                 //   Modulo-2
```

- The `n.bitCount(n&n*2)` is ported from [*@CommandMaster*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266997/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
- The `1|-...%2` is shorter than `Math.pow(-1,...)` in Java.

Comment: `n->1|-n.bitCount(n&n*2)%2` seems to work?

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 5 bytes

```
bᵃ×∑Ṃ
```

[Try it Online! (link is to literate version)](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJsIiwiIiwidG8tYmluYXJ5XG50by1wYWlyczogdGltZXNcbnN1bVxubmVnMSoqIiwiIiwiNDYxIiwiMy4xLjAiXQ==)

<s>Vyxal 3 doesn't currently have the `-1 **` and `push -1` built-ins v2 has.</s> It does now. Can't believe I forgot them.

### Explained (old)

```
bᵃ+2C1_$*­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
b          # ‎⁡Convert to list of digits in binary representation
 ᵃ+        # ‎⁢Reduce each overlapping pair by addition
   2C      # ‎⁣Count the number of 2s in that list
     1_$*  # ‎⁤-1 ** that
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 31 bytes

```r
\(x)(-1)^sum(x%/%2^(0:30)%%4>2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7YzQqNDV0DTXjiktzNSpU9VWN4jQMrIwNNFVVTeyMNCGq1hUnFhTkVAIlDC110qCCCxZAaAA)

A function taking an integer and returning -1 or 1. I’ve assumed integers in the range 0 to 2^31 - 1, since that is the range for non-negative integers in R.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Jp¢ä* x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=SnCi5CogeA&input=NDYxLVE) or [run it on each n from 0 to 20](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=VSsiIC0%2bICIrXA&code=SnCi5CogeA&input=MjAtbVI)

Explanation:

```
J        -1
 p       to the power of
  ¢        the input in binary
   ä       each pair of digits reduced by
    *        multiplication
      x    sum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) machine code, 12 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> = 15 bytes

*<sub>1. CP-1610 instructions are encoded with 10-bit values (0x000 to 0x3FF), known as DECLEs. Although the Intellivision is also able to work on 16-bit data, programs were really stored in 10-bit ROM back then.</sub>*

A routine taking the input in **R0** and returning the result in **R1**.

```
                            ROMW  10        ; use 10-bit ROM
                            ORG   $4800     ; map our code at $4800
                      
4800  02B8 01CD             MVII  #461, R0  ; example call with n = 461
4802  0004 0148 0006        CALL  func
4805  0017                  DECR  R7        ; loop forever
                      
                            ;; Our routine
                            ;; We start with R1 = 1.
                            ;; We negate R1 for each bit set in R0 AND (R0 >> 1).
                      func  PROC
                      
4806  02B9 0001             MVII  #1,   R1  ; R1 = output, initialized to 1
4808  0082                  MOVR  R0,   R2  ; copy R0 to R2
4809  0062                  SLR   R2        ; right-shift R2
480A  0182                  ANDR  R0,   R2  ; bitwise AND of R0 and R2
                      
480B  007A            @loop SARC  R2        ; right-shift R2 into carry
480C  0209 0001             BNC   @next     ; skip NEGR if the carry is not set
480E  0021                  NEGR  R1        ; negate R1
480F  022C 0005       @next BNEQ  @loop     ; loop if the last result is non-zero
                                            ; (always true if NEGR was processed,
                                            ; otherwise based on SARC R2)
                      
4811  00AF                  MOVR  R5,   R7  ; return
                      
                            ENDP
```

### Output

```
Returned from JSR at $4802.
 01CD FFFF 0000 0000 01FE 4805 02F1 4805 ------i-  DECR R7
      \__/
     R1 = -1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 45 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 5.625 bytes

```
bzvΠ∑Ǎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsImJ6ds6g4oiRx40iLCIiLCI0NjFcbjBcbjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjEwXG4xMVxuMTJcbjEzXG4xNFxuMTVcbjE2XG4xN1xuMThcbjE5Il0=)

Bitstring:

```
011100100001001101011110010110110000010001101
```

Comment: Fun fact: passing the bitstring of the Vyncode representation as input to the program gives a result of -1. [Test it](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiQiIsImJ6ds6g4oiRx40iLCIiLCJcIjAxMTEwMDEwMDAwMTAwMTEwMTAxMTExMDAxMDExMDExMDAwMDAxMDAwMTEwMVwiIl0=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x<1or(1-x%4//3*2)*f(x>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr@wl2o3EtE5S/sUoa6FUxIO93mbSV@4Y5tb89rh3PxxUU1cVMypRu0XKedA0eKzWKmo@ZmDgANmF60Q9kYGUORTkEXph@xE8MlH7AQ)

Comment: @JonathanAllan oops, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<3or(3>n&3or-1)*f(n//2)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Y4v0jD2C5PDUjrGmpqpWnk6esbaf4vKMrMK9GIBhFAIU1NhbT8IoU8hcw8haLEvPRUDTMTzVjN/wA)**

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 37 bytes

```
.+
*
+`(_+)\1
$1;
vC`_;_
.+
*
__

$
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hck9DkBAFEbR/q6DBJOIz/9EqbAJyRuFQqMQsf0h2nOu/T7OTTHNlhBLR4ELmbl8FYkmnjnYZPxhBgmKsULUNLR09AyMePShUI0a1KIO9WhAI/Iv)

Given \$ n \$ yields \$ r_{n} \$. The header in the link allows it to be run on many values at once. Uses `_` as the negative sign.

#### Explanation

```
.+
*
```

Convert decimal to unary.

```
+`(_+)\1
$1;
```

Convert unary to binary (sort of).

```
vC`_;_
.+
*
```

Count overlapping "1"s in the binary representation, and then convert that to unary.

```
__

$
1
```

Remove pairs of digits in unary to delete even numbers and leave one digit for odd numbers. Then add a 1 to the end of the output. Because the digits are underscores, we get the desired expression.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term of the sequence. Relies on arithmetic underflow to stop the recursion.

```javascript
f=n=>n?(-n%4/3|1)*f(n/2):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PXkM3T9VE37jGUFMrTSNP30jTyvB/Wn6RRk5qiUKegq2CgTWQslEwAtHa2poK1VwKCsn5ecX5Oal6OfnpGgmJGirVebWaQKUq1UATNGsTNK25av8DAA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = n =>   // f is a recursive function taking the input n
n ?        // if n is not zero:
  (        //
    -n % 4 //   the sign of n % m is the sign of n in JS,
           //   so this gives a value in ]-4, 0]
    / 3    //   we turn this into a value in ]-4/3, 0]
           //   this is ≤ -1 if the 2 least significant bits
           //   of the integer part of n are set
    | 1    //   a bitwise OR with 1 gives either:
           //     -1 for ]-4/3, -1]
           //      1 for ]-1, 0]
  )        //
  *        //   we multiply by the result of ...
  f(n / 2) //   ... a recursive call with n / 2
           //   once we have n < 1, the final result is not
           //   changed anymore; and once n is small enough,
           //   n / 2 will eventually be evaluated to 0
:          // else:
  1        //   stop the recursion
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 39 bytes

```
.+
$*_
+`(_+)\1
$1;
(_);\b|.
$1
__

$
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@nzaWidWgbF5eKXgKXqoZ7AkQknks7QSNeWzPGkEvF0JpLI17TOiapRg/I4YqPByrmMvz/38gAAA) Takes `n` as input but link is to test suite that generates all the results from `0..n` inclusive. Explanation: Based on @FryAmTheEggman's Retina 1 answer, with the following changes:

- Retina 0.8.2 uses `M&` where Retina 1 uses `vC`.
- Retina 0.8.2's character repetition operator `$*` is already a byte longer than Retina 1's string repetition operator `*`, plus it defaults to the character `1` which is unhelpful, so an explicit character is needed. Fortunately the latter only makes a difference on the last use.
- I then golfed a byte off by replacing the count and subsequent unary conversion stage with a replace stage. (This would also work in the Retina 1 answer, but there it wouldn't affect the byte count.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
﹪Ｌ⌕Ａ⍘Ｎ²11²1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3P6U0J1/DJzUvvSRDwy0zL8UxJ0fDKbE4NbgEqCBdwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHwQiIlQwNlTTBbE1rLogxSkAR6///TcwM/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th term. Explanation:

```
     Ｎ      Input number
    ⍘ ²     Convert to base `2` as a string
  ⌕Ａ   11   Find all overlapping matches of `11`
 Ｌ          Count them
﹪        ²  Reduce modulo `2`
            Implicitly print that many `-`s
          1 Append a literal `1`
```

The naïve approach of raising `-1` to the power of the count of overlapping matches actually ends up longer as an additional byte is required to cast the result to a string.

Comment: A really clever way to output the minus sign.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 35 bytes

```perl
$_=(-1)**unpack"%b*",pack N,$_&2*$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvNCoJAGEbh/bmKEIsaFHw/Z0ZddAvdglS0iESHfm6/yXaHB066PaeQczke97UOzn3mdL4@iu3FFdW/NqeqHHfmyjHnBmG0eAKRjp4BrShkqEUeBRRRh3o0YA22Poa1mMcCPuq7pPd9mV@5TtMP)

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets / Microsoft Excel, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
=-1^len(substitute(base(bitor(A1,2*A1),2),0,))
```

Put \$n\$ in cell `A1` and the formula in `B1`.

Using the method in Command Master's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266997/119296), with -1 byte thanks to [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752/m90).

In spreadsheets, operator precedence is sometimes different from what one would expect. The unary minus will get evaluated before exponentiation, so `-1^2` === `(-1)^2` === `1` rather than `-1`.

Comment: Improvement: change `bitand` to `bitor`. Compared to the AND result, the OR result has an extra 1 bit for every `01` or `10` bit pair in the bits of the original number with 0 bits added at the start and end. The number of `01` pairs is necessarily equal to the number of `10` pairs, thus the number of extra 1 bits in the OR result is even.

Comment: @m90 thanks for the -1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, 25 bytes

```
prod(1-2seq(3=4fPart(int(Ans/2^I)/4),I,0,Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), 37 bytes

```
{for(;$1>1;$1/=2)a+=$1%4>=3}$0=(-1)^a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhY3VavT8os0rFUM7QyBhL6tkWaitq2KoaqJna1xrYqBrYauoWZcIkQxVM-CxSZmhhAmAA) or [try more test cases.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYs7CsJAAAX7OceKCRLM2182yOYogk0aC0EUC_EkNguSQ-U2CcRmimHm-7u8rqVMz8fYpHn_Hm_36mQ0aMUx29rYQzba-SG7j2lz1ag-G7vl_6vMoUVYHJ5ApCPRo1UKWeSQRwFF1KGEenzUdi8)

Takes `n` from stdin and prints the `n`th term to stdout. Multiple-case version has `a` replaced with `$2` so that it works across test cases.

Awk numbers are floating-point numbers. The for loop observes the 0th and 1st bits while the given number is shifted to the right. Both bits are 1 if and only if the current number modulo 4 (floating-point) is at least 3.

Comment: Nice answer ! You out-golfed me by so much... Otherwise for multiple test case you don't need to use `$2` you can set `a=0` in the footer.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```apl
×/¯1*2∧/⊢⊤⍨2⍴⍨!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/TeFR2wSFw9P1D6031DJ61LFc/1HXokddSx71rjB61LsFSClypRNUA@T//6@uYKCgrpOmYMBVklpcUgzW9Kh3s6EllwZYQFMn2lDPNDb90AqofO9chYKi1JKSSoW0/KLcxJKSzLx0AA)

Written as a tacit function. While this would technically work for all n, it will run out of memory very quickly, as it computes n as a binary number with n! digits. This is simply to avoid the edge case of n=0, so the following code works equivalently and much more efficiently for positive n (only using n digits).

```apl
×/¯1*2∧/⊢⊤⍨2⍴⍨⊢
```

Would be interested if there were a workaround to this issue that doesn't increase byte count.

EDIT: I swapped the Power and the Reduce and changed from a Plus reduction to a Times reduction to remove parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

*-4 bytes building off of a suggestion made by [@Yousername](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91262/yousername)!*

*-1 more byte also from [@Yousername](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91262/yousername) building off of my 44 byte golf*

```
f(k)=∏_{n=0}^ksgn(5-2mod(floor(k/2^n),4))
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iuig6cilnb?nographpaper)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qjegwaifz4?nographpaper)

Comment: 46 bytes: `f(k)=∏_{n=0}^k(1-0^{3-mod(floor(k/2^n),4)}2)`

Comment: @Yousername Thanks for the suggestion! Using product is clever; I found a way to shave two more bytes off building off of your idea!

Comment: 1 byte less based off of your new one: `f(k)=∏_{n=0}^ksgn(5-2mod(floor(k/2^n),4))`

Comment: @Yousername Nice! That looks about as short as it can get.

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>67 65 59 58</strike> 56 bytes

```
{d=and($1,$1*2);for(b=z;d/=2;)b=d%2b}$1=(-1)^gsub(1,1,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCgIxEAXA/TtHhEQi4@v5htBXEdIEXQgKigwoc/aMtayy3lv7VS2P6h2j41FCvj5f3vSba6eSg2k9iG2O6k8Ml9v7Y56R0UJrZxCCHgNGTJixIIH/JChgDw7gCE7gDC5g2gE)

- -2 bytes, didn't use the regex indicator in `gsub()`, just passed `1` as first arg
- -6 bytes, removed `int()` function, then used `d/=2` instead of `d=d/2`
- -1 byte, moved the divisor of `d` in the conditional statement
- -2 bytes, moved the `$1` assignment

This works for multiple record input. If your file would only have a single record you could save <strike>`3`</strike> `4` bytes by replacing the initialization of `b` in the `for()` loop with the initialization of `d`.

---

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>53</strike> 52 bytes

```
{for(d=and($1,$1*2);d/=2;)b=d%2b}$1=(-1)^gsub(1,1,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEAXQ/T9HCkmJ2D9qVGSuUnAI7aLQQkUEi2ePfcs3b69iupff4/P1Wed39o7R8SphyrXKFEzzRexwVF8x3J/Lap6R0UIpNxCCBi06JPQYMIL/JChgA7ZgByawBwdwPAE)

- -1 byte, moved the `$1` assignment

I'm not completely familiar with each and every rules allowed for golfing. So in this case I moved the initialization of `b` in the header. This allow having multiple record read in one go. <strike>Secondary I moved the `1` at the end of the line to the footer. We already have our value stored in the current record, adding `1` at the end of the line trigger the default `awk` block `{print $0}` so it's only useful for printing.</strike>

Any insight of the rule on both of these subjects are more than welcome !

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 26 bytes

Prompts for integer:

```
¯1*+/2=2+/((⌈2⍟2⌈n)⍴2)⊤n←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6H1hlra@ka2Rtr6GhqPejqMHvXONwLSeZqPercYaT7qWpIHVAzU9B@onOt/GpcBVxqXIRAbAbExEJuYGXJxAQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 3L](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 28 bytes

```
2to-base count: */+-1swap **
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJsIiwiIiwiMnRvLWJhc2UgY291bnQ6ICovKy0xc3dhcCAqKiIsIiIsIjQ2MSIsIjMuMC4wIl0=)

I know the byte counter says "10 literate bytes", but that's going to be changed in the future to properly accommodate literate mode golfing.

Anyhow, I thought this might be a fun opportunity to try out literate mode golfing and see how it plays out. And it's definitely interesting - I started with 32 bytes using the exact SBCS method, but found that adding some extra commands made it shorter. Aliases!

The `3L` stands for Vyxal 3 Literate Mode. It's different to Vyxal 3 `l` flag, as 3L (in theory) has a dedicated executable. I say in theory because I may or may not have forgotten to actually make it a release binary - it can still be run from mill though.

### Explained

```
2to-base count: */+-1swap **­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
2to-base                      # ‎⁡Convert input to base 2. Shorter than `to-binary`
         count: *             # ‎⁢Reduce overlaps by multiplication. The space is needed so that the "*" is recognised as an individual word.
                 /+           # ‎⁣Reduce that by addition. `/+` beats `sum` by a byte
                   -1swap     # ‎⁤Push -1 under that value
                          **  # ‎⁢⁡And exponentate
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>42</s></sup> 28 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n?f(n/2)^n%4/3*-2:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFfa4MwEMDf@ykOQUiswdVuD5tzexj7FNOBxKSTtbGYwGTiV192VauztKMhOS6/@5fccbbh3FpJFG1UrJ5RCUL6rtzbYO2x8GEVtbZQBnZZoQiFZgG4DkDUe8GNyN9SiKFZ@dBvdkab7mzi7NQ2006cL2e8utYFdK7G1a/8N6qNul7xUmkD/COrPJSCf4qqb5mT1K9hUt@/4LlzfPh7XztDtCwrIId2FyoXNYbdRIP6CLr4FqUkx0HQYADeSCJYLjtv2iXrh3ccoMFsnTGaYY1YEkPnVCAdJ95FpZPDvkIXSRw3B/YEKF2dKPyR8UH746d1HIt0SNsuWvvD5TbbaMu@LNvufgE)

*Port of [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267001)*

*Saved a whopping 14 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)!!!*

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZFfa4MwEMDf@ykOQUiswdVuD5tzexj7FNOBxKSTtbGYwGTiV192VauztKMhOS6/@5fccbbh3FpJFG1UrJ5RCUL6rtzbYO2x8GEVtbZQBnZZoQiFZgG4DkDUe8GNyN9SiKFZ@dBvdkab7mzi7NQ2006cL2e8utYFdK7G1a/8N6qNul7xUmkD/COrPJSCf4qqb5mT1K9hUt@/4LlzfPh7XztDtCwrIId2FyoXNYbdRIP6CLr4FqUkx0HQYADeSCJYLjtv2iXrh3ccoMFsnTGaYY1YEkPnVCAdJ95FpZPDvkIXSRw3B/YEKF2dKPyR8UH746d1HIt0SNsuWvvD5TbbaMu@LNvufgE) porting xnor's [second Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267001)

Comment: @att Awesome - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 18 bytes

```
~..+&2base{},,-1\?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05PT1vNKCmxOLW6VkdH1zDG/v9/EzNDAA) or [try numbers 0 to 30](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvbKBTraSkrfe/Tk9PW80oKbE4tbpWR0fXMMb@v5KCrZ2CUoy2dq1qntZ/AA).

`-1` raised to the power (`\?`) of the number of truthy items (`{},,`) of the binary representation (`2base`)  of the bitwise AND (`&`) of the input (`~`) and it doubled (`..+`).

Here’s a solution that doesn’t use bitwise operations:

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 27 bytes

```
~2base.);\(;+2/{{*}*},,/-1\?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84oKbE4VU/TOkbDWttIv7paq1arVkdH1zDG/v9/EzNDAA) or [try numbers 0 to 30](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvbKBTraSkrfe/zigpsThVT9M6RsNa20i/ulqrVqtWR0fXMMb@v5KCrZ2CUoy2dq1qntZ/AA).

Full program.

Explanation <s>coming soon to a theater near you</s> has arrived at a codeblock near you!

```
~     # Eval the input (reading it as a number)
2base # Concert it to a list of binary digits
.     # Duplicate
);    # Remove the last of the copy
\(;   # Remove the first of the original
+     # Concatenate them
2/    # Split into groups of size two
{    },, # Number of pairs where following is true:
 {*}*    #   Reduce by multiplication
-1\?  # Raise -1 to this power
```

No builtin for overlapping pairs, so this instead makes two copies - one with the first digit removed and one with the last removed - concatenates them, and splits into nonoverlapping pairs.

Answer (score 3):

## WebAssembly (text), <strike>131</strike> 130 bytes

```
(func(param i32)(result i32)i32.const 1
i32.const -1
local.get 0
local.get 0
i32.const 2
i32.mul
i32.or
i32.popcnt
i32.ctz
select)
```

A WebAssembly function that, given `n` as a 32-bit integer, returns the `n`th term of the sequence.

[ctz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Reference/Numeric/Count_trailing_zeros), [popcnt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Reference/Numeric/Population_count)

-1 byte thanks to @m90

Equivalent to the pseudocode `ctz(popcnt(n | n*2)) ? 1 : -1`, which is equivalent to `ctz(popcnt(n & n*2)) ? 1 : -1`. If the result of popcnt is odd, then ctz will return 0. Else (if the result of popcnt is even), ctz will return a non-zero value. Therefore, it is also equivalent to the pseudocode `popcnt(n & n*2) & 1 ? -1 : 1`.

Line endings are counted as a single byte (`\n`).

For a fully valid WebAssembly text module (which does not export the function), <strike>139</strike> 138 bytes:

```
(module(func(param i32)(result i32)i32.const 1
i32.const -1
local.get 0
local.get 0
i32.const 2
i32.mul
i32.or
i32.popcnt
i32.ctz
select))
```

For a fully valid WebAssembly text module, where the function `f` can be accessed by the (JavaScript) code that loads the module, <strike>151</strike> 150 bytes:

```
(module(func(export "f")(param i32)(result i32)i32.const 1
i32.const -1
local.get 0
local.get 0
i32.const 2
i32.mul
i32.or
i32.popcnt
i32.ctz
select))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Improvement: change `and` to `or`. Compared to the `and` result, the `or` result has an extra 1 bit for every `01` or `10` bit pair in the bits of the original number with 0 bits added at the start and end. The number of `01` pairs is necessarily equal to the number of `10` pairs, thus the number of extra 1 bits in the `or` result is even.

Comment: @m90 thanks! post has been updated

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
d⋏b∑Ǎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBIiwiIiwiZOKLj2LiiJHHjSIsIiIsIjBcbjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjQ2MSJd)

Uses Command Master's trick.

```
    Ǎ # -1 **
   ∑  # Sum of
  b   # binary of
 ⋏    # n &
d     # n * 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>57</del> <del>55</del> 52 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @m90

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

---

```scala
n=>1-Integer.parseInt((n&n*2).toBinaryString,13)%2*2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU7BasJAEL37FY-gZVeMaPRQghH01oO9SE_iYaq7ISXOymS1iORLvHixl36Rf9PV9MHM8Gbee8zlp9pQSaPfVRSz-ybhaH1_d59fZuOxoIJxbgFbY7ELRJHkVYqZCJ1WSy8F52ud4oMLjywog_RIJWwK9cY-m4amkd0O3sav9zFn02EcViY30t-TVCYQpfiFu4nuezcvmOTUxPaGI91Jusm_d4YA60QxJjEG8A7JQD9_e2AfLL5kVUVt7qF9top1HenntW49qm6Crtdm_gE)

Comment: Improvement: remove the parentheses around `n*2`. (This works the same way because `*` has higher precedence than `&`.)

Answer (score 2):

## ARM64 machine code, 24 bytes

This function takes a 64-bit integer in `x0` and returns the result in `x0` as well, following usual calling conventions.

```
8a000401
d2800020
ab010021
da803400
54ffffc1
d65f03c0
```

Assembly source:

```
        .global rudin_shapiro
        .text
        .balign 4
rudin_shapiro:
        and     x1, x0, x0, lsl #1
        // Now x1 has a 1 bit for each 11 in the input.  It remains to
        // compute its parity.
        mov     x0, #1
next_bit:
        adds    x1, x1, x1      // shift left into carry flag
        cneg    x0, x0, cs      // negate x0 if a 1 was shifted out
        b.ne    next_bit        // continue if result of adds was not zero

        ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 30 bytes

```matlab
@(n)hadamard(2^n*2)(n+1,2*n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoAgEEDRvacYBEHNRF0GRQeJQBqlFo0h0fXNv3jLX443fqnl2VrbVknqjBjvWFGGnXRQkgZvgu6qlksFghnc5B2D3lMverPkAmFcQOBG3AAZyP2jWCJsPw)

This sequence are the entries \$W_{n+1,\ 2n+1}\$ of the infinite [Walsh matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162254/9288) \$W\$.

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica), <strike>48</strike> 12 bytes

*-36 bytes thanks to @alephalpha*

```mathematica
RudinShapiro
```

Takes \$n\$ as the input and outputs the \$n\$-th term of the Rudin-Shapiro sequence.

Comment: `RudinShapiro` is already a valid answer. You don't need to add `[n]`.

Comment: @alephalpha How would the byte count be calculated then? `ByteCount[RudinShapiro]` just returns 0 in Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: There are 12 ASCII chars, so 12 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 19 bytes

```
pw(-1)<sm<pa ml<bs2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GuzNyC_KIShYCi1JzSlFQFDU0umMjS0pI0XYutabYF5Rq6hpo2xbk2BYkKuTk2ScVGELlduYmZebYp-VwKCgVFCioKaQo2CtEGenpGBrEQBQsWQGgA)

### Explanation

- `bs2` convert to binary (integer values)
- `pa ml` multiply consecutive values
- `sm` sum
- `pw(-1)` raise -1 to the power of the result

## 19 bytes

```
pw(-1)<l<fa[T,T]<bi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GuzNyC_KIShYCi1JzSlFQFDU0umMjS0pI0XYutabYF5Rq6hpo2OTZpidEhOiGxNkmZELlduYmZebYp-VwKCgVFCioKaQo2CtEGenpGBrEQBQsWQGgA)

### Explanation

- `bi` convert to binary (boolean values)
- `fa[T,T]` find all occurrences of `[T,T]` (11)
- `l` get the number of such occurrences
- `pw(-1)` raise -1 to the power of the result.

## 19 bytes

```
pw(-1)<cnT<pa mp<bi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NYw7DoJAFEV7VnELCyiGoJUFLMDOgs5YDPAmTpxfHgPGtdjQGFdg407cjRBidZNzTu7jdZH9lYyZvqxt8BxxZDJDR0iz5E8SIdC6GrqH8xFylNrIxhC8g4wed4r50hwU4oWYllA6ELNnMFk_0ixm2PqOkuWpQkuon0NUYv9WVbilYpuVsymDhA1lo1f3sVK7qvMJEBgbKJQ4FXm-K85rME3r_gA)

### Explanation

- `bi` convert to binary (boolean values)
- `pa mp` combine consecutive values with and
- `cnT` count the number of `True`s
- `pw(-1)` raise -1 to the power of the result

## Reflection

- [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271311/56656) I expressed a need for a shortcut to `(-1)`.  I still have not implemented that.
- `pw(-1)` on it's own is probably worth having a built in.
- Having a shortcut for `pa mp` would be useful.
- There should be a function to take *from* a certain base *to* an integer.
- There should be a built in that combines `l` and `fa` to count the number of occurrences of a substring.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, <s>63</s> 38 bytes

```swift
let f={-($0*2&$0).nonzeroBitCount%2|1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 38 bytes

```
f(n)=(-1)^hammingweight(bitand(n,n*2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BCsIwFET3OcXgQpKS0tqVIL2BZ1AibdpA-xPiLyLiSdx0I57J2xipLmYzzJuZxyuY6I5dmOfnxDbfvtdWkqplvlGH3oyjo-7Suq5neXJsqJGkKauU-qWbnSgy7L0PsNGPKMEeVYmURIiOGNy3iO15GhjewoQwXFMnLLJC3IT1URJqlDpRekGSsYJO-j5RStyXrf_DDw)